# What happens when there is object exactly in the focus of converging lens?

Tags: optics, lenses

I was learning some optics and then I wondered what would happen if some object was exactly in the focus of converging lens, more accurately, what would I see if looking from the other side?

EDIT: so there would be candle. The candle would be exactly at focus. The tip of the flame would be "sending" rays of light toward the lens. Parallel ray would hit the lens and then go right towards focus while vortex ray would go through the vortex of the lens unchanged but parallel to the first ray so there would be no place where the image would create right?

I mean, the light rays would be parallel and they would never form an image.. probably.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll have to explain your set up better.

Comment: Set up is described.

Comment: When you say "focus" do you mean "focal point?"  If so, then any standard physics text will explain the geometrical rays.

Comment: An ideal lens with an object in the focal point will produce an approximation of the Fourier transform of the object. This can and has been used for analog computing devices that calculate Fourier transforms to perform spatial and temporal filtering at the ns or even sub-ns time scale.

Comment: @CuriousOne Ok, I will have to find out some stuff since I do not know what Fourier transform is. I will ask if I dont understand anything.

Comment: @BillN Yeah thanks for correction. I am not native speaker so for this I was using google translate.

Comment: If the flame is at the focal point, then the rays hitting the lens will be diverging from the focal point, not parallel.  When they emerge from the lens on the other side, *then* they will be parallel, and no image will form.  Hope that helps.